# Problem with starting web site on Vista & IIS 7 via .NET

Tags: c#, iis-7, windows-vista, active-directory

I need to get IIS web-site state programmatically via C#. I usually do it this way:

```
DirectoryEntry DE = new DirectoryEntry( string.Format( "IIS://localhost/W3SVC/{0}", siteID ) );
Int32 serverState = (Int32)DE.Properties["ServerState"][0];
if ( serverState == IISHelper.MD_SERVER_STATE_STOPPED )
     DE.Invoke("Start", new object[] { });
```

But this code does't work on Windows Vista, serverState is always 4 (Stopped) even if the site is running and DE.Invoke("Start", new object[] { }) throws Interop exception.

**How can i do this on Vista?**

Thanks.

Comment: IIRC you can make this work by installing the IIS 6 compatability metabase option from Programs and Features, but there is a better IIS 7+ way too.

Comment: IIS 6 compatability is installed